# Vue keep-alive nested components

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent Vue component and inside it a child component. Parent component is wrapped in "keep-alive" tag.

When there is no include provided for keep-alive, both component state is preserved (components doesn't get destroyed when navigating):

```
<keep-alive>
  <parent>
    <child/>
  </parent>
</keep-alive>
```

If I add include to each individual component keep-alive it also works:

```
<keep-alive include="parent">
  <parent/>
</keep-alive>
<keep-alive include="child">
  <child/>
</keep-alive>
```

But when I add include to nested components, it doesn't work any more:

```
<keep-alive include="parent, child">
  <parent>
    <child/>
  </parent>
</keep-alive
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/203sbk8n/1/

Comment: Ok it sometimes works, sometimes not and it also depends on include component sequence. I guess I will dump keep-alive and try to save the state with vuex.

https://jsfiddle.net/axsnd86b/2/

Comment: update your vue and router version and problem has gone